# What is the meaning of 's' in {l s='Accept PayPal' mod='paypal'}

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, smarty3

I'm new to Prestashop. While learning I found this

```
{l s='Accept PayPal' mod='paypal'}
```

I'm curious what does **s** means in the above statement. I know **l** is for the language but I don't know the meaning of **s**.

Answer (score 2):

**`s` means *string* and is the string to be translated.**

`l()` is a custom Smarty function that we added in PrestaShop to make templates (.tpl files) translatable.

We registered it in `/config/smarty.config.inc.php` on line 86:

`smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, 'function', 'l', 'smartyTranslate', false);`

And then added it to `\config\smartyfront.config.inc.php` and `config\smartyadmin.config.inc.php`:

```
function smartyTranslate($params, $smarty)
```

**You can use the following parameters:**

---

`mod` To be used only within module templates (.tpl) files, with the name of the related module

Example: `{l s='My module text' mod='mymodulename'}`

---

`js` To be used within JavaScript code blocks, the translated content will be escaped

Example: `var my_var = '{l s='Delete' d='Admin.Actions' js=1}';`

---

`pdf` To be used in reference to a pdf file

Example: `{l s='Note' d='Shop.Pdf' pdf='true'}`

---

`d` To be used in reference to a specific translation file

Example: `{l s='No menu' d='Admin.Advparameters.Feature'}`

---

`sprintf` To be used if you have variables within the translated string

Example: `{l s='My variable is %s' sprintf=[$my_var|escape:'html':'UTF-8']}`

---

**You can find more information in the PrestaShop 1.7 documentation [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/internationalization/translation/).**

Answer (score 0):

the "s" just mean "string", and "l" is "language", so why to not use "m" instead of "mod" ;)